# C# UWP GridView DataTemplate bindings issue

Tags: c#, gridview, binding, uwp, datatemplate

I have created a GridView. I have set a ItemTemplate to it.

```
        <GridView x:Name="gvMain"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridTemplate}"  
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  CanDragItems="True" 
                  CanReorderItems="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding gridViewCarsScrollViewVisible, ElementName=carsControl}">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate" x:DataType="models:Car">

        <Grid
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                  
              Background="Transparent"
              Tapped="CarTapped">

                <Border x:Name="borderBackground" 
                    Background="White" 
                    Opacity="{x:Bind IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource TransparencyConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>                  

        </Grid>     

    </DataTemplate>
```

In my model I have a property:

```
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set { isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

And I am changing it:

```
    private void CarTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;
        var car = grid.DataContext as Car;

        car.IsSelected = !car.IsSelected;
    }
```

There are, for example 300 cars in gridview. The problem is when I start scrolling down, binding goes to IsSelected property for each car that will be shown, no matter if I go up, down...if I return to already "loaded" cars still the binding is looking for property value. And if there are more properties, it will go to each one of them if the binding is set on some control. This makes scrolling impossible, since it is very choppy because of this.

Why is binding trying to get value whenever the item is scrolled into view?
I tried to use binding instead of x:bind, I tried to set mode: One way, Two way, One time...I tried to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged...but each time the same result.

Any clue what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot/GIF of what exactly is happening? That helps in understanding the issue better

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are disabling UI Virtualization with this data template, because the Grid is completely dynamically sized. Try setting the size of the Grid explicitly to restore virtualization.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview for more.

Comment: Grid in DataTemplate or GridView?

Comment: The Grid in the DataTemplate